# C++11 support in NetBeans IDE 7.3.1

Tags: c++, netbeans, c++11, macros, autocomplete

I have a question regarding C++11 support in NetBeans IDE 7.3.1. I am using a Microsoft Windows 7 operating system and [Minimalist GNU for Windows](http://mingw.org) v4.8.1 and therefore g++ (GCC) v4.8.1. I am also able to compile C++11 specific code (e. g. `auto` or `std::shared_ptr`) by adding the flag `-std=c++11` to the C++ Compiler. This can be achieved via the GUI of NetBeans IDE, by selecting *Project Properties*, *C++ Compiler*, *C++ Standard*.

Although I am able to compile and run C++ specific code, the autocompletion of the IDE doesn't work correctly. I will demonstrate this behavior with an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
  auto foo = 5;
  auto bar = std::make_shared<std::string>();
  bar.get();
}
```

The above code causes an error in NetBeans IDE on line 7: `Unable to resolve identifier shared_ptr`. **But::** The STDOUT displays `201103` and (as I said) I am able to compile and run the code. `auto` doesn't cause an error, btw.

When I change the value of the macro `__cplusplus` via *Options*, *Code Assistance*, *C++ Compiler* to `__cplusplus=201103L` the above error on line 7 is gone, but I still get an error on line 8: `Unable to resolve identifier get`.

So my question is: How can I activate autocompletion for C++11 in NetBeans IDE 7.3.1? Do I have to add specific directories to the system includes or add more macro values? I did not modify any of the default MinGW includes, yet.

**EDIT:** After resetting the Compiler settings in NetBeans IDE back to their default values, I am not retrieving an error on line 7, but only on line 8. Is it possible that NetBeans hasn't yet the autocomplete functionality for C++11?

Regards.

Comment: I have error on my netbean IDE too, for example `constexpr` is ok sometime and sometime it's underlined in red. But, everything compile, so I'm ok with that. Look at [this page about your problem](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214186)

Comment: Unrelated style comment: Prefer to instantiate `shared_ptr`s with `make_shared`: `auto bar = std::make_shared<std::string>();` It's more concise and better performing.

Comment: This still seems to be a problem in Netbeans 8.0.2. Atleast mine is doing that and it's pretty annoying.

Comment: I am using [QT Creator](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator) instead of NetBeans IDE now. It is so much better. I recommend to not use NetBeans IDE for serious C++ development.

Comment: Thanks, but i find QT Creator highly annoying cause of a lot of usability bugs (try having two documents open and scrolling in one of them...)

Comment: Which version of Qt Creator do you use? I've not run into serious problems using 3.2.0 and 3.3.0.

Comment: Following up in the comment for 8.0.2. If I define "__cplusplus=201103L"  via [Tools> Options> Code Assistance> C++ Compiler] the problem is not fixed, but if I right click the project, then open [Properties > Code Assistance > C++ Compiler], and there I change the C++ standard to C++11 AND define in "Preprocessors definitions" __cplusplus=201103L the code assistance problem in line 8 in the example above is gone with many others in my projects. Still a few c++11 misses left, but a lot better.