# Incorrect C++ Autocompletion in NetBeans IDE 8 using MinGW/Cygwin

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, cygwin, mingw

I am using the following combination for C++ development:

- Microsoft Windows 8.1 x64
- [MinGW Distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) 11.6
- [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) 1.7.28
- [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp) IDE 8.0

First of all: I am able to compile source code both with MinGW and with Cygwin. The problem I describe in this question is related to **both** environments (or NetBeans).

Depending on the C++ standard to use for the project (see screenshot), the autocompletion doesn't work correctly in NetBeans IDE. In addition the behaviour of the autocompletion isn't consistent between using MinGW and Cygwin.

[image: C++ Standard in NetBeans IDE 8.0]

If using C++98 with MinGW Distro, the "new" language features of C++11 aren't auto-completed (*correct behaviour*):

[image: C++98 Autocompletion in NetBeans IDE 8.0]

If using C++11 with MinGW Distro, the "new" language features of C++11 are auto-completed, but `std::vector` (maybe some others too) isn't **fully** autocompleted (*incorrect behaviour*):

[image: C++11 Autocompletion in NetBeans IDE 8.0]

If using Cygwin, I am unable to get autocompletion to work correctly with `std::vector` at all, regardless of the C++ standard choosen in the IDE.

Therefore I assume that the problem is maybe related to some missing or superflucios macro definitions in the NetBeans IDE configuration for each environment.

Again: I am able to compile the code, regardless of the auto completion errors.

1. What can cause the problem described?
2. Do you know a solution for the problem?

I already asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045504/c11-support-in-netbeans-ide-7-3-1) some time ago. The problems described there seem to be fixed in NetBeans IDE 8.0, since new C++11 features are detected properly.

Comment: Did you reparse your project after switching to C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update 1* has been released to NetBeans 8.0, which fixes many bugs according C++11 and it's code assistance. You can see the fixed bugs [here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?status_whiteboard=80patch1&status_whiteboard_type=allwordssubstr). Please update and test again.

Comment: I tested it and it does fix my particular problem. I think it has been fixed with this issue: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242729. Thank you for your answer!